# To retrieve value from a text box in a form (view) to controller in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

How to o retrieve value from a text box in a form (view) to controller in cake php?

Comment: Are you asking the basic question of how do you handle POST'd data in a controller?  That's basic-basic stuff; you'll do best to read the introduction to CakePHP articles that are all over google.  Also check out the Cake manual.  Please put some effort into figuring things out for yourself before posting a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the CakePHP book on saving your Model data:

```
function edit($id) {
    //Has any form data been POSTed?
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        //If the form data can be validated and saved...
        if($this->Recipe->save($this->data)) {
            //Set a session flash message and redirect.
            $this->Session->setFlash("Recipe Saved!");
            $this->redirect('/recipes');
        }
    }

    //If no form data, find the recipe to be edited
    //and hand it to the view.
    $this->set('recipe', $this->Recipe->findById($id));
}
```

If your model was Recipe, and your input was named "title", then the value would be in $this->data['Recipe']['title'], if you setup your view like so:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Recipe');

echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
echo $this->Form->input('title');

echo $this->Form->end('Save Recipe');
```

So, look here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

And try to do the Blog tutorial, it might help you get started:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog